# Case Insensitive MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, collation, case-insensitive

On my MySQL database, my collation is set to `utf8_general_ci`. I also checked the collation of table in my database. This should allow for case insensitive queries. However all queries are still are still case sensitive.

For example, this query will not work if I have the username with the first letter capitalized.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM   users 
  WHERE  username = 'test' 
  AND    password = 'test'
```

I am using MySQL 5.5.27 Community edition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collation set to `ci` (case-insensitive) only affects the way you search in data, not columns. IIRC, column names are case sensitive and table names aren't.

Follow a standard naming convention for your database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about databases set to be case insensitive, but you can use Lower()

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Lower(username) = 'test' AND lower(password) = 'test'
```

Comment: This will work, but be warned it does a [table scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) so it's very slow. You can store a normalized form (`strtolower()` in php before inserting or querying) to take advantage of an index.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the @mauris answer. 
Otherwise you use strtolower($username) in php and

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) = 'test' AND password = 'test'
```